# slideUp() all the elements but not the selected ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

All I want to do is:

- there are 7 numbers and 7 divs, they are linked to each other (nr 0 it's in a relationship with div 0)
- when one of the numbers is clicked, it should collapse all the other divs which are not selected
- it can be selected more at one time

To sum up, basically, the page has some labels with numbers and 7 divs which are all displayed by default (the divs), but when one or more of them are chosen by clicking on the numbers, the page should display only the chosen divs.

This is what I've been trying to do:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {     
            if(i != (floors[i])) {
                $("#lvl" + floors[i]).slideUp();
            }
        }
```

More code:
    http://jsfiddle.net/LSjg4/

Comment: can u explain more wat exactly are u trying to achieve?

Comment: I have 7 numbers (7 spans) and 7 divs. If I click on a number, I want the div that belongs to number x to be shown (if it's not) and collapse all the other divs which are not selected.

Comment: so exactly opposite to wat it is now??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected a few things in your code. Here is the below working code and link to it in jsfiddle.

There was a data type mismatch(comparing string and int). When matching whether it exists in floors array, the code was checking floors[i] only whereas the i can be any position in floors.

```
var floors = [];
$(".nr").click(function () {
        var state = $(this).data('state');
        state = !state;

        if (state) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#1b7664");
            $(this).css("border-color", "#236959");
            floors.push(parseInt($(this).text()));
            console.log(floors);

            for(var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {  
                ret = $.inArray(i, floors);
                if(ret==-1) {
                    $("#lvl" + i).slideUp();
                }
                else {
                     $("#lvl" + i).slideDown();
                }
            }

        } else {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#02c099");
            $(this).css("border-color", "#13a480");
            for (var i = 0; i < floors.length; i++) {
                if (floors[i] == parseInt($(this).text()))
                    floors.splice(i, 1);
            }
             for(var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {  
                ret = $.inArray(i, floors);
                if(ret==-1) {
                    $("#lvl" + i).slideUp();
                }
                else {
                     $("#lvl" + i).slideDown();
                }
            }

        }
        $(this).data('state', state);
    });
```

Demo Here: http://jsfiddle.net/bFe9T/

Comment: @Xmsss did you check my answer, it provides the same functionality with a lot less code

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var floors = [];

var $lvls = $('.lvl'), $nrs = $(".nr");
$nrs.click(function () {
    var $nr = $(this), index = $nrs.index($nr), $lvl = $lvls.eq(index);

    $lvl.add($nr).toggleClass('active');

    if($nr.hasClass('active')){
        $lvls.not('.active').slideUp();
        $lvl.slideDown();

        $nr.css("background-color", "#1b7664");
        $nr.css("border-color", "#236959");
        floors.push(($nr).text());
    } else {
        $nr.css("background-color", "#02c099");
        $nr.css("border-color", "#13a480");

        if($nrs.filter('.active').length == 0){
            $lvls.slideDown();
        } else {
            $lvls.not('.active').slideUp();
        }
        var text = $nr.text();
        floors.splice($.inArray(text, floors), 1);
    }

    console.log('floors', JSON.stringify(floors))
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CT2Gh/)

Comment: It's a good answer, but after deselecting the elements, it has to show them all again (all the divs that belong to the numbers).

Comment: @Xmsss after deselecting all elements?

Comment: after selecting the numbers, all of the levels should be shown. If you deselect the numbers, each level will disappear (which is good). But when all of the numbers are deselected, I need to display all the levels.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".nr").click(function () {
    //alert($(this).attr("data-select"));
    if($(this).attr("data-select") === "1") {
        $(this).attr("data-select","0");
    } else {
        $(this).attr("data-select","1");
    }

    $(".nr").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("data-select") === "1") {
            var id = $(this).text();
            $("div#lvl"+id).slideDown();
        } else {
            var id1 = $(this).text();
            $("div#lvl"+id1).slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LSjg4/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
$(".nr").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $('.nr').each(function(){
        var $target =  $('#lvl'+$(this).text());
        if($(this).is('.selected'))
            $target.slideDown();
        else
            $target.slideUp();
    });
});
```

Note that instead of changing the CSS properties I set up a class for the selected elements

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LSjg4/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>slideUp demo</title>
  <style>
      .norm { background:#cccccc; margin:3px; width:80px;height:40px; float:left;color:#000000 }
      .faded { background:#ffffff; margin:3px; width:80px;height:40px; float:left;color:#ffffff }
      .btn{width:80px;}
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="btn" onClick="show(1)">1</button>
  <button class="btn" onClick="show(2)">2</button>
  <button class="btn" onClick="show(3)">3</button>
  <button class="btn" onClick="show(4)">4</button>
  <button class="btn" onClick="reset()">Reset</button>
  <div class="norm" id="slide1">1</div>
  <div class="norm" id="slide2">2</div>
  <div class="norm" id="slide3">3</div>
  <div class="norm" id="slide4">4</div>

  <div></div>
<script>
  var save = new Array();
  function show(indx){
        if($.inArray(indx, save)==-1){
            save.push(indx);
            for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
                if($.inArray(i, save)==-1){
                    $('#slide'+i).attr('class','faded');
                }
                else{
                    $('#slide'+i).attr('class','norm');
                }
            }
        }
  }
  function reset(){
    save = new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){       
        $('#slide'+i).attr('class','norm');
    }
  }
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```